# How to dynamically add API requests to a pool and then run it with Laravel's HTTP client?

Tags: laravel, gmail-api

I'm trying to download thousands of emails with the Gmail API. I found that it is better to batch requests when downloading a large amount of data. And I want to achieve that with [Laravel's HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client) because I saw it can pool requests and it sounds like exactly what I need.

But I want to create the pool dynamically. I have undownloaded emails (emails for which I only have a gmail id and I must make another API call to get the email content). I manage to create a pool beforehand :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;

$pool = new Pool();
    
foreach ($emails as $email) {
    $pool->withToken($user->googleAccessToken()->value)->get('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/' . $email->email_id);
}
```

but then I don't know how to run it with the client because `Http::pool` expects a callback.

I tried doing something like this instead :

```
$user = Auth::user();
$emails = $user->emails()->where('downloaded', false)->get();
$responses = Http::pool(function(Pool $pool) {
   foreach ($emails as $email) {
       $pool->withToken($user->googleAccessToken()->value)->get('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/' . $email->email_id);
   }
});
dd($responses);
```

but I just get `Undefined variable $emails`.

What I'd like to do is retrieve all these not downloaded emails from my db and send batches of 100 requests to the Gmail API, with a script like below (but with URLs added dynamically):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Pool;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
 
$responses = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) => [
    $pool->get('http://localhost/first'),
    $pool->get('http://localhost/second'),
    $pool->get('http://localhost/third'),
]);
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation on how to implement the batch request with sample codes from the [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch#overview). It might help you give you an idea, I am aware on a way to do multiple  batch request with AppScript.

Comment: Thank you @RicardoJoseVelasquezCruz yes I saw the link but that doesn't help me to do it in Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're not including your `$emails` variable in the closure. It should be

```
$responses = Http::pool(function(Pool $pool) use($emails) {
   foreach ($emails as $email) {
       $pool->withToken($user->googleAccessToken()->value)->get('https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/' . $email->email_id);
   }
});
```